# Display Text with ImageView in Gridlayout

Tags: java, android, view, android-gridlayout

I have already achieved this with GridView but because I was not able to span columns in GridView(which I can only achieve with GridLayout), I have to do same with Gridlayout.

Has anyone been able to achieve this with GridLayout?

[image: ImageView with Text]

I was adding view to the GridLayout like this:

```
ImageView twoByOne3 = new ImageView(this);
    GridLayout.LayoutParams third = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row2, col1);
    third.width = halfScreenWidth;
    third.height = halfScreenWidth;//quarterScreenWidth;
    twoByOne3.setLayoutParams(third);
    twoByOne3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.jobs);
    gridLayout.addView(twoByOne3, third);
```

I decided to add a FrameLayout with ImageView and TextView so as to display Text on the ImageView like this :

```
    FrameLayout view1 = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
    ImageView imv1 = (ImageView)view1.findViewById(R.id.ivFullScreenAd);
    imv1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.thumb1);

    TextView txtv1 = (TextView)view1.findViewById(R.id.detailTitle);
    txtv1.setText("Test Text");

    GridLayout.LayoutParams first = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row1,
            colspan2);
    first.width = screenWidth;      
    view1.setLayoutParams(first);
    gridLayout.addView(view1, first);
```

Comment: What you have tried to achieve same?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK K I have edited my question to show what I have tried to do but it failed.

Comment: @Gordons: and what currently you are getting using current code?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK  I get an error  "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mtechcomm.mtechlifestyle/com.mtechcomm.mtechlifestyle.MenuScreenActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException 
: E/AndroidRuntime(1124):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
02-20 03:30:54.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1124): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-20 03:30:54.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1124):  at com.mtechcomm.mtechlifestyle.MenuScreenActivity.onCreate(MenuScreenActivity.java:53)"
Line 53 points at : ImageView imv1 = (ImageView)view1.findViewById(R.id.ivFullScreenAd);

Comment: @Gordons: then add full log with question to check where getting issue

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK K The error is on Line 53 : ImageView imv1 = (ImageView)view1.findViewById(R.id.ivFullScreenAd);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling with this for days, I have been able to get it to work. I created an XML file containing an ImageView and TextView(in a transparent container) put in a FrameLayout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
android:paddingBottom="2dp"
android:paddingLeft="2dp"
android:paddingRight="2dp"
android:paddingTop="2dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivFullScreenAd"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/images_are_here"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/magric" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#bbffffff"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detailTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:gravity="bottom|center"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:text="Please swipe up"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then I created the Activity View like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container_scroll_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
tools:context="com.mtechcomm.mtechlifestyle.MenuScreenActivity">    
    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/menu_holder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fadingEdge="vertical"/>
 </ScrollView>
```

Then in my Activity, I created the GridLayout like this :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.Spec;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MenuScreenActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

GridLayout gridLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_screen);

    gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.menu_holder);

    gridLayout.setColumnCount(2);
    gridLayout.setRowCount(15);

    DisplayMetrics display = new DisplayMetrics();
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(display);

    int screenWidth = display.widthPixels;
    int screenHeight = display.heightPixels;
    int halfScreenWidth = (int) (screenWidth * 0.5);

    Spec row1 = GridLayout.spec(0, 2);
    Spec row2 = GridLayout.spec(2);
    Spec row3 = GridLayout.spec(3);
    Spec row4 = GridLayout.spec(4);
    Spec row5 = GridLayout.spec(5);
    Spec row6 = GridLayout.spec(6);
    Spec row7 = GridLayout.spec(7);

    Spec col0 = GridLayout.spec(0);
    Spec col1 = GridLayout.spec(1);
    Spec colspan2 = GridLayout.spec(0, 2);

    /*
     * Create the first image here
     *       
     */
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(MenuScreenActivity.this);
    View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.inflated_gridview, null);

    ImageView imv1 = (ImageView) promptsView
            .findViewById(R.id.ivFullScreenAd);
    imv1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.entertainment_gist));

    TextView txtv1 = (TextView) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.detailTitle);
    txtv1.setText("Gist");

    GridLayout.LayoutParams first = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row1,
            colspan2);
    first.width = screenWidth;
    promptsView.setLayoutParams(first);
    gridLayout.addView(promptsView, first);

    /*
     * Create the second image here
     */

    LayoutInflater twoByOne2inflater = LayoutInflater
            .from(MenuScreenActivity.this);
    View twoByOne2 = twoByOne2inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflated_gridview,
            null);

    ImageView bnImg = (ImageView) twoByOne2
            .findViewById(R.id.ivFullScreenAd);
    bnImg.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.breaking_news));

    TextView bbText = (TextView) twoByOne2.findViewById(R.id.detailTitle);
    bbText.setText("Breaking News");

    GridLayout.LayoutParams second = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row2, col0);
    second.width = halfScreenWidth;
    second.height = halfScreenWidth;
    twoByOne2.setLayoutParams(second);
    gridLayout.addView(twoByOne2, second);

    /*
     * This is where we create the third image
     */

    LayoutInflater twoByOne3inflater = LayoutInflater
            .from(MenuScreenActivity.this);
    View twoByOne3 = twoByOne3inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflated_gridview,
            null);

    ImageView jobsImg = (ImageView) twoByOne3
            .findViewById(R.id.ivFullScreenAd);
    jobsImg.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.jobs));

    TextView jobsText = (TextView) twoByOne3.findViewById(R.id.detailTitle);
    jobsText.setText("Jobs");

    GridLayout.LayoutParams third = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row2, col1);
    third.width = halfScreenWidth;
    third.height = halfScreenWidth;
    twoByOne3.setLayoutParams(third);
    gridLayout.addView(twoByOne3, third);

    /*
     * This is where we create the fourth image
     */

    LayoutInflater twoByOne4inflater = LayoutInflater
            .from(MenuScreenActivity.this);
    View twoByOne4 = twoByOne4inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflated_gridview,
            null);

    ImageView mAgricImg = (ImageView) twoByOne4
            .findViewById(R.id.ivFullScreenAd);
    mAgricImg.setImageDrawable(getResources()
            .getDrawable(R.drawable.magric));

    TextView mAgricText = (TextView) twoByOne4
            .findViewById(R.id.detailTitle);
    mAgricText.setText("mAgric");


    GridLayout.LayoutParams fourth = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row3, col0);
    fourth.width = halfScreenWidth;
    fourth.height = halfScreenWidth;
    twoByOne4.setLayoutParams(fourth);
    gridLayout.addView(twoByOne4, fourth);

    /*
     * This is where we create the fifth image
     */
    LayoutInflater twoByOne5inflater = LayoutInflater
            .from(MenuScreenActivity.this);
    View twoByOne5 = twoByOne5inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflated_gridview,
            null);

    ImageView mHealthImg = (ImageView) twoByOne5
            .findViewById(R.id.ivFullScreenAd);
    mHealthImg.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.mhealth));

    TextView mHealthText = (TextView) twoByOne5
            .findViewById(R.id.detailTitle);
    mHealthText.setText("mHealth");


    GridLayout.LayoutParams fifth = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row3, col1);
    fifth.width = halfScreenWidth;
    fifth.height = halfScreenWidth;
    twoByOne5.setLayoutParams(fifth);
    gridLayout.addView(twoByOne5, fifth);

    /*
     * This is where we create the sixth image
     */
    LayoutInflater twoByOne6inflater = LayoutInflater
            .from(MenuScreenActivity.this);
    View twoByOne6 = twoByOne6inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflated_gridview,
            null);

    ImageView sportsImg = (ImageView) twoByOne6
            .findViewById(R.id.ivFullScreenAd);
    sportsImg.setImageDrawable(getResources()
            .getDrawable(R.drawable.sports));

    TextView sportsText = (TextView) twoByOne6
            .findViewById(R.id.detailTitle);
    sportsText.setText("Sports");


    GridLayout.LayoutParams sixth = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row4, col0);
    sixth.width = halfScreenWidth;
    sixth.height = halfScreenWidth;
    twoByOne6.setLayoutParams(sixth);
    gridLayout.addView(twoByOne6, sixth);

    /*
     * This is where we create the seventh image
     */
    LayoutInflater twoByOne7inflater = LayoutInflater
            .from(MenuScreenActivity.this);
    View twoByOne7 = twoByOne7inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflated_gridview,
            null);

    ImageView callerTunesImg = (ImageView) twoByOne7
            .findViewById(R.id.ivFullScreenAd);
    callerTunesImg.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.callertunes));

    TextView callerTunesText = (TextView) twoByOne7
            .findViewById(R.id.detailTitle);
    callerTunesText.setText("Caller Tunes");


    GridLayout.LayoutParams seventh = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row4,
            col1);
    seventh.width = halfScreenWidth;
    seventh.height = halfScreenWidth;
    twoByOne7.setLayoutParams(seventh);
    gridLayout.addView(twoByOne7, seventh);

    /*
     * This is where we create the eight image
     */
    LayoutInflater twoByOne8inflater = LayoutInflater
            .from(MenuScreenActivity.this);
    View twoByOne8 = twoByOne8inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflated_gridview,
            null);

    ImageView christianContentImg = (ImageView) twoByOne8
            .findViewById(R.id.ivFullScreenAd);
    christianContentImg.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.christain_content));

    TextView christianContentText = (TextView) twoByOne8
            .findViewById(R.id.detailTitle);
    christianContentText.setText("Christian Contents");

    GridLayout.LayoutParams eight = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row5, col0);
    eight.width = halfScreenWidth;
    eight.height = halfScreenWidth;
    twoByOne8.setLayoutParams(eight);
    gridLayout.addView(twoByOne8, eight);

    /*
     * This is where we create the nine image
     */
    LayoutInflater twoByOne9inflater = LayoutInflater
            .from(MenuScreenActivity.this);
    View twoByOne9 = twoByOne9inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflated_gridview,
            null);

    ImageView islamicContentImg = (ImageView) twoByOne9
            .findViewById(R.id.ivFullScreenAd);
    islamicContentImg.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.islamic_content));

    TextView islamicContentText = (TextView) twoByOne9
            .findViewById(R.id.detailTitle);
    islamicContentText.setText("Islamic Contents");

    GridLayout.LayoutParams nine = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row5, col1);
    nine.width = halfScreenWidth;
    nine.height = halfScreenWidth;
    twoByOne9.setLayoutParams(nine);
    gridLayout.addView(twoByOne9, nine);

    /*
     * This is where we create the tenth image
     */
    LayoutInflater twoByOne10inflater = LayoutInflater
            .from(MenuScreenActivity.this);
    View twoByOne10 = twoByOne10inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.inflated_gridview, null);

    ImageView blogImg = (ImageView) twoByOne10
            .findViewById(R.id.ivFullScreenAd);
    blogImg.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blog));

    TextView blogText = (TextView) twoByOne10
            .findViewById(R.id.detailTitle);
    blogText.setText("Blog");

    GridLayout.LayoutParams ten = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row6, col0);
    ten.width = halfScreenWidth;
    ten.height = halfScreenWidth;
    twoByOne10.setLayoutParams(ten);
    gridLayout.addView(twoByOne10, ten);

    /*
     * This is where we create the eleventh image
     */
    LayoutInflater twoByOne11inflater = LayoutInflater
            .from(MenuScreenActivity.this);
    View twoByOne11 = twoByOne11inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.inflated_gridview, null);

    ImageView mnsImg = (ImageView) twoByOne11
            .findViewById(R.id.ivFullScreenAd);
    mnsImg.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.mobile_newspaper));

    TextView mnsText = (TextView) twoByOne11.findViewById(R.id.detailTitle);
    mnsText.setText("Mobile Newspaper");

    GridLayout.LayoutParams eleven = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row6, col1);
    eleven.width = halfScreenWidth;
    eleven.height = halfScreenWidth;
    twoByOne11.setLayoutParams(eleven);
    gridLayout.addView(twoByOne11, eleven);

    /*
     * This is where we create the twelfth image
     */
    LayoutInflater twoByOne12inflater = LayoutInflater
            .from(MenuScreenActivity.this);
    View twoByOne12 = twoByOne12inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.inflated_gridview, null);

    ImageView worldClockImg = (ImageView) twoByOne12
            .findViewById(R.id.ivFullScreenAd);
    worldClockImg.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.world_time_zone));

    TextView worldClockText = (TextView) twoByOne12
            .findViewById(R.id.detailTitle);
    worldClockText.setText("World Clock");

    GridLayout.LayoutParams twelve = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row7, col0);
    twelve.width = halfScreenWidth;
    twelve.height = halfScreenWidth;
    twoByOne12.setLayoutParams(twelve);
    gridLayout.addView(twoByOne12, twelve);

    /*
     * This is where we create the thirteenth image
     */
    LayoutInflater twoByOne13inflater = LayoutInflater
            .from(MenuScreenActivity.this);
    View twoByOne13 = twoByOne13inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.inflated_gridview, null);

    ImageView worldStockImg = (ImageView) twoByOne13
            .findViewById(R.id.ivFullScreenAd);
    worldStockImg.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.world_stock_market));

    TextView worldStockText = (TextView) twoByOne13
            .findViewById(R.id.detailTitle);
    worldStockText.setText("World Stock");

    GridLayout.LayoutParams thirteen = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row7,
            col1);
    thirteen.width = halfScreenWidth;
    thirteen.height = halfScreenWidth;
    twoByOne13.setLayoutParams(thirteen);
    gridLayout.addView(twoByOne13, thirteen);
}
}
```

This might not be the best solution though.